# Create Defect in Rally using REST API and C#

Tags: rally

I am trying to programatically create a defect in Rally using C#. Below is my code and errors i am getting is

```
Error in creating defect!!!
Cannot parse object reference from "Unspecified"
```

Code:

```
       RallyRestApi restApi;
       restApi = new RallyRestApi(webServiceVersion: "v2.0");
       //after successful authentication...

       String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345";
       String projectRef = "/project/78321";  


        DynamicJsonObject badDefect = new DynamicJsonObject();
        newDefect["Name"] = "Defect " + DateTime.Now;
        newDefect["Project"] = projectRef ;
        newDefect["Environment"] = "test branch";
        newDefect["c_DefectSourceNEW"] = "old";
        newDefect["Severity"] = "minor";         
        newDefect["Release"] = "Unspecificed";

        CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create("Defect", newDefect);

        if (createResult.Success == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Defect created Successfully!!!");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in creating defect!!!");
        }

        foreach (string s in createResult.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Can some one suggest what i might be doing incorrectly and in general the correct way to sepcify "Release" value for a defect???

Answer (score 0):

All object relationships in wsapi are represented by refs.  So you just need to set the value as its ref rather than its name, much like you're already doing with workspace and project.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for your comment. You mean for Defect.Release i should be doing like   newDefect["Release"] = "Release/Unspecifed" ??? or should i be using identifier for Release? I see there is a way to get Project ID and Workspace ID but not Release ?

Comment: Yes: newDefect["Release"] = "/release/12345";  You'll have to do a query to find the specific release you're looking for beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kyle for inputs. Since the Release ID was mandatory i solved by below for Release Input:

```
  Request reRequest = new Request("Release");
            reRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            reRequest.Query = new Query("Project", Query.Operator.Equals, projectRef);
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(reRequest);
            string reprojectRef = null;
            foreach (DynamicJsonObject result in queryResult.Results)
            {

                reprojectRef = result["_ref"];
                Console.WriteLine(reprojectRef);

                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + result["Name"]);

                if (result["Name"] == "MyReleaseName")
                {
                    newDefect["Release"] = result["_ref"];

                }

            }
```